# How can I add text to the beginning of multiple text files using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I want to add text to the beginning of multiple .txt files in Windows.

For example, I want to add my name to the beginning of all the .txt files in a folder. I have tried:

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do type myname >> %%a
```

(where myname is a file containing my name)

But that adds the line to the end of the file which is not what I want.

Is there a similar way to add text to the beginning of all of my .txt files?

**EDIT:**

After trying out a few things I came up with this:

```
@echo off
    for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    copy /b myname + %%a %%a.txt
    move "%%a.txt" "%%a"
)
```

This works correctly and puts the text contained in the file myname at the top of each .txt in the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you're asking. Basically it's creating a new file with my name at the top, then appending the original file to it. Then deletes the original and renames the new file to the originals name. No reason you couldn't 'type' any file to the beginning by replacing my echo statement.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
echo ---- %%a before ----
type "%%a"
echo --------------------

echo 'bert' > "%%a.tmp"
type "%%a" >> "%%a.tmp"
del "%%a"
move "%%a.tmp" "%%a"

echo ---- %%a affter ----
type "%%a"
echo --------------------
)
```

The output I get is:

```
C:\Users\Bert\Documents\test>addMyNameToTop.bat
---- C:\Users\Bert\Documents\test\test.txt before ----
testing 1-2-3
--------------------
        1 file(s) moved.
---- C:\Users\Bert\Documents\test\test.txt affter ----
'bert'
testing 1-2-3
--------------------

C:\Users\Bert\Documents\test>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't work for me. This just replaces all text in each file with 'bert'.

Comment: Interesting. I've added a bit of logging and an example of the results I get. Are there any error messages when you run it? After trying again with the updated code, please include the output in a follow up comment. I recommend testing with one .txt file in the directory to limit the amount of output.

Comment: This still replaces everything in the text file with 'bert' complete with the quotes. I am fairly new to batch files, how do I see the cmd output as it instantly closes when done.

Comment: @Spaaacce, two ways. 1) run it from the command line or 2) add 'pause" (without the quotes) to the end of the batch file.

Comment: When viewing the output the problem was clear. The directory in which all this was happening contains a folder with a space in its name. This folder was not handled very well and cut off at the space meaning the file could not be found. I changed the location of everything and it now works fine.

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out! I updated the script once more so that it could work with spaces in file paths. Basically added quotes around all the filename variables. Your solution is good as long as the text to be prepended is expected to be in a file.

Comment: Answer accepted thanks for all your help! As I am new to this, could you tell me if there is anything wrong with the solution I came up with in my edit. Both solutions work I was just wondering if one is better form than the other.

Comment: Yours is more versatile because it can prepend your files with different text from the myname file. Mine would require you to edit the batch file to change the text which is a bigger maintenance problem.

Comment: Ah good point. Thanks again for your help :)